# Как собрать проект мавен без группового ид?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, intelij

Возможно ли собрать проект мавен без group id? Как собрать мавен таким образом, чтобы в идее можно было начать создавать классы/пакеты сразу внутри директории src?

Comment: А зачем? Вы можете и так создавать классы и пакеты сразу внутри `src`. Чем вам мешает `group id`? Оно не обязательно должно совпадать с вашими пакетами, насколько я помню. Но это так называемые "правила приложения"

Comment: Дело в том, что я не могу создавать классы внутри src, В src мавеном генерируются две папки - main и test, внутри которых, в свою очередь, находится папка названная по group id, и только в этой директории идея разрешает создавать классы. Простите за глупые вопросы, я совсем еще зеленый :c

Comment: а внутри `src` и не надо. Ваша "точка отправления" начинается с `src/main/java/`. Вот там и создавайте Вашу структуру

Comment: принято, спасибо)